# Spring Security custom method with path variable and ant matcher

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring boot, web MVC and spring security with java configuration. My URLs are 'RESTful' and would like to add custom authorisation methods.

For Example:

```
.antMatchers("/path/*/**").access("@myBean.authorise()")
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
.antMatchers("/path/{token}/**").access("@myBean.authorise(token)")
```

I understand that I can pass in the `HttpServletRequest` and manually strip the path, but would like to avoid this! Also not too keen on method level security, would rather keep the config in one place as I have many controllers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access path variables, just prefix them with `#`.  In your case, the correct syntax would be:

```
.antMatchers("/path/{token}/**").access("@myBean.authorise(#token)")
```

I'm not sure when this was introduced, but I know it is now supported. Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/el-access.html

Comment: If anyone is looking for the expired link shared above, here is the guide:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/el-access.html