# AntMatchers path variable Spring security

Tags: java, spring-security

I using antMatchers for set permission and role, but i cann't handle path variable for it. Please help me

```
.antMatchers("/admin/code/certificate/{id}/proc")

                .access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_CERTIFICATE_EDIT', 'ROLE_CERTIFICATE_ALL')")
            .antMatchers("/admin/code/certificate/*")
                .access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_CERTIFICATE_VIEW', 'ROLE_CERTIFICATE_EDIT', 'ROLE_CERTIFICATE_ALL')")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33115446/authorization-in-spring-security-based-on-path-variables

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421357/spring-security-custom-method-with-path-variable-and-ant-matcher

Comment: i using 2th of you answer. But server response 405 method not allowed

Comment: @PathVariable is a id for i update a object with a post submit form

Comment: 405 has nothing to do with security. If you use `POST` you need a controller method for `POST`.

Comment: i using @PostMapming for controller. But it not working.